# How to connect to a mysql database from Django?

Tags: mysql, django, wamp

I have an `inscription.sql` on a WAMP localhost:80 server, and I have also Django running on visual studio via a localhost:xxxx server.

I want to connect Django to the mysql database located on the wamp server (I have successfully installed MysqlClient).

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the MySQL database from Django ?

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry :(

Comment: What will you do with the MySQL database once you connected Django to it? Do you want to use the ORM?

Comment: To give you the context : I am using Django to make a inscription form for new students in university, and I need for security purpose to have a separate server for the database and the application. I will insert form from Django into the Mysql database and be able to print them on papers directly from the admin panel of Django. Is this possible ? am I clear to you ? thanks for your help

Comment: Is Django already connected to a database?

Comment: I am not sure but I think he is connected to a mysqldb created inside the python folder in lib/site-package/mysqldb, not sure. I don't quite understand this thing.

Comment: What is the value of the `DATABASES` setting (look for it in `<project_name>/settings.py`)?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'inscription', 
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/) to using an already existant database with Django.

To sum up, what you need to do is:

- Make sure Django can connect to your database by setting the right `DATABASE` setting. From your comment, this seems to be the case.
- Generate models (Python code) that match the tables in your database using the `python manage.py inspectdb` command. You must paste the generated code in the `models.py` file of an installed app and review them to make sure they fit your needs.
- Create the tables required by Django with the `python manage.py migrate` command.

Comment: First of all, don't link to an image.  Copy and paste your traceback into your question.  Notice  admindjango ... you are missing a . between admin and django in some import statement

Comment: Okay thanks I found it @joel goldstick. Everything seems to have worked, but I can't watch the tables inside the admin panel (http://localhost:xxxx/admin/) is this normal ?

Comment: Do your models have ModelAdmin classes?  Are they listed in setup.py under INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',

Comment: I searched for ModelAdmin class on internet but this thing seems very complicated and I am not even sure if it is what I need to display my tables in the admin panel ?!

Comment: Yes, it is what you need and no it is not that complicated, you should go through the Django tutorial if you have not yet.

Comment: Okay I have read some tutorials and from what I understood I need to write admin.py with 'from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)' inside (source: http://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter06.html#adding-your-models-to-the-admin-site)

Comment: The problem is in this scenario he is actually using models he generated in Django while in my case I need to do the same but by importing tables from my mysqldb directly. Any idea on how to do it ? I feel I am close to the solution ^^

Comment: You use the models you generated with `python manage.py inspectdb`

Comment: But where did they get generated ? I can't find them thanks

Comment: You need to specify where the `inspectdb` command saves them. This way: `python manage.py inspectdb > path_to_the_file_where_you_want_your_models.py`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)

Jus set the DATABASES variable in settings, then run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` put the generated `models.py` in the app's folder and finally run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Your problem is that you are using an image file.  Open a new question and post the code in your question.  Surround your code with three backtics ``` and it will show with proper indentation